# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named postgres. Maven project

Tags: java, maven, jpa, eclipselink

I just got started with JPA and for some reason I get this error:

> May 18, 2022 10:47:45 AM
> javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver
> log WARNING: javax.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.
> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No
> Persistence provider for EntityManager named postgres     at
> javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:86)
> at
> javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
> at Main.testJPA(Main.java:17)   at Main.main(Main.java:64)

The persistance unit name matches the one in the code. Here's proof:

```
public static void testJPA() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf =
                Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("postgres");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Continent continent = new modelbase.Continent("1","Europe");
        em.persist(continent);

        Continent c = (Continent)em.createQuery(
                        "select e from ContinentEntity e where e.name='Europe'")
                .getSingleResult();
        c.setName("Africa");
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
```

This is the persistance.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
  <persistence-unit name="postgres"
              transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
  <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  <properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
              value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
              value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
              value="4563"/>
  </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Been trying to get past this error for 2 hours now and can't seem to figure out why.
Also this is the pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>LAB9</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please don't provide either of these: code, error messages, terminal commands as images. Always include them as a **text** formatted appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You use a latest version of persistence xml based on jakarta xsd (3.0) but you use javax.persistence to connect to your database.

You juste have to use :
org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider

```
<property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="Driver ..."/>
<property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:..."/>
<property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
<property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="psw"/>
```

and include the folloin artifacte in you'r pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
 </dependency>

-- Or


 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core-jakarta</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.9.Final</version>
 </dependency>
```